# C++ cout prints string incorrectly after erasing newline characters?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I had a multiline string:

> 123 456 7
>   8910

for example. I erased all newline characters '\n' in a function `int clean(string& text);` and printed the string in the main using `cout`. The result was:

> 8910456 7

I know my function works "right" because, the result of `str.substr(0, 5)` is:

> 123 4

Also, I had another multiline string printed out via `cout` correctly, so `cout` is working correctly. Also included `string` and `iostream` libraries.

```
int clean(string& text) {
    //...
    text.erase(std::remove(text.begin(), text.end(), '\n'), text.end());
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    string t1;
    string name1 = "../test.txt";
    try {
        t1 = readBlock(name1);
        cout << t1 << endl;
    } catch(exception &e) {
        cout << e.what();
    }
    cout << "Size: " << t1.size() << endl;
    clean(t1); //Here
    cout << t1 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Other methods, erasing the newlines, like adding every character except newlines to a new string, resulted in the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were your 'newline' characters actually `\r\n` rather than just `\n`?

Comment: There is still a carriage return in your string. Remove the \r also.

Comment: Look at the actual contents of the string using your debugger, and preferably in some "raw" view of the data.  You cannot rely on `cout` statements to tell you what the characters are.

Comment: The above comments are probably correct, but we need an [mcve] to be sure. For all we know `readBlock` contains nothing but dancing cats.

Answer (score 3):

Your line endings are (I infer from your result) actually `\r\n` rather than just `\n`.  That is a Carriage Return byte, followed by a Line Feed byte.

You are then outputting the first line to `cout` which prints the string to the console.  You're then hitting the carriage return (`\r`) byte which, when output to the console, puts the cursor back to the start of the line.  The second line is then output to the console, but still on the same row, and it is printed over the top of the existing text.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: actually, this was exactly the answer. thank you! I just erased all '\r' characters and it worked.